How do I use layoutparser in python? There is an error AttributeError 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'detect'
this is my code..
import layoutparser as lp
from PIL import Image

model = lp.AutoLayoutModel('lp://EfficientDete/PubLayNet')
image = Image.open("/Users/kim-yelim/Desktop/test2/papers.jpg")

if model is None:
    print("Model failed to load. Check the model URL or dependencies.")
else:
    layout = model.detect(image)

there is a problem "Model failed to load. Check the model URL or dependencies."
I think the model is wrong, but I don't know why..
I've installed everything related to layoutparser, I've installed detectron2, I've double-checked the image path, and I'm still getting the error.
If I clear the if statement, I get the following error
Exception has occurred: AttributeError 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'detect'
How to fix this problem??

According to https://github.com/Layout-Parser/layout-parser/issues/136, this means that "AutoLayoutModel cannot find a model to instantiate".

When lp.AutoLayoutModel fails to load or fetch a model from the specified URL, it returns None. This is why you're encountering the error: ' NoneType' object has no attribute 'detect' . You may try model = lp.AutoLayoutModel('lp://PubLayNet/efficientdet/PubLayNet') 

Check your internet connection or firewall if they block that connection
model = lp.AutoLayoutModel('lp://EfficientDete/PubLayNet')

this will download models weights.
That's why you got this error
